# c# serial port listener

Tags: c#, serial-port

Is in C# any serial port listener, that will call my function if there will be any data on serial port?
My only idea is to use infinite loop, something like this:

```
while true
    if someDataOnSerialPort
        callmyfunction(serialPortData)
```

?
Any handler that will call my function if there will be any data?
Thanks.

Comment: Great question. Ridiculous that it was closed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is use the [`DataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event to be notified that new data and call your function from inside that event handler instead of inside a infinite loop.

Here is the example from the MSDN modified slightly to use your function names

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        //Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        //Console.Write(indata);

        callmyfunction(indata);
    }

    private static void callmyfunction(string data)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing to console works, but in line callmyfunction(indata), i get an error : `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ` How to fix it?

Comment: @parman woops, forgot to put the word `static` in the function declaration, updated answer.