# C# Threaded Serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to figure out how to communicate with Arduino (or any serial device in general) and "listen" for any messages sent by Serial device (in this case Arduino).
Arduino board can send events at any time and I need to capture them in my C# app.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to use Threading properly as examples I've found do "not fit" the code I have (below). I've red documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 but this is nearly totally different and I could not figure out how to incorporate it in my example.

I can Open port and send message to Arduino by any Event from C# application. But I am missing continuous reading part.
When ever I open port and listen for new messages *`serialPort->ReadLine()`*, it blocks completely. Messages are showing in console but it's blocking the rest of the app.

What would be the way to implement continuous listening and calling *`processSerialCommunication`* function when ever new message is received, without blocking any other piece of application?

PS: I've tried this and does not work on my example: [c# serial port listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018001/c-sharp-serial-port-listener)

**My example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;


namespace arduinoCommunicator {
    void ArduinoInterface::init() {
        serialPort = gcnew SerialPort(ComPort, 115200);
        try {
            serialPort->Open();
            has_serial = true;

            Console::WriteLine("#### Arduino serial port is open on port");
            this->sendArduinoCommand("\n");
            this->sendArduinoCommand("ON");


            // This is blocking part
            String^ message = serialPort->ReadLine();
            if(message != ""){
                this->processSerialCommunication(message);
            }


            serialPort->Close();
            has_serial = false;

        }
        catch (IOException ^ ex) {
            Console::WriteLine("Could not write data to the port");
        }
    }

    bool ArduinoInterface::sendArduinoCommand(String^ commandString) {
        if (has_serial) {
            Console::WriteLine("Seding this to arduino: " + commandString + "");
            try {
                serialPort->Write(commandString);
            }
            catch (IOException ^ ex) {
                Console::WriteLine("Could not send data to arduino");
            }
        }
        serialPort->Close();
        return true;
    }
    void ArduinoInterface::processSerialCommunication(String^ args) {
        Console::WriteLine("Some data received: " + args);
        // Do something with data...
    }
}
```

Comment: This article doesn't use threads, but it will be helpful. [Simplest serial port terminal in C#](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2009/04/18/simplest-serial-port-terminal-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be looking for solution, I've managed to setup Threading and have continuous Serial port reading.

Sending something to Serial while reading is in progress works as well. Comparison of received string does not work as expected and it's something ToDo. If anyone has and advice on this, it's welcome to comment below.

Basic working Example:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::IO;
    using namespace System::IO::Ports;
    using namespace System::Threading;


    namespace arduinoCommunicator {
        void ArduinoInterface::init() {
            serialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM4", 115200);
            // ##### Version v2.
            Thread^ readThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &ArduinoInterface::readArduinoSerial));
            String^ DataReceiving;
            String^ message;
            serialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
            try {
                serialPort->Open();
                has_serial = true;
                readThread->Start();

                Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Green;
                Console::WriteLine("#### Arduino serial port is open on port");
            }
            catch (IOException^ ex) {
                Console::WriteLine("Could not open Serial port");
            }
            // ####### End version v2
        }

        bool ArduinoInterface::sendArduinoCommand() {
            if (has_serial) {
                Console::WriteLine("Seding this to arduino: " + commandString + "");
                try {
                    serialPort->Write(commandString);
                }
                catch (IOException ^ ex) {
                    Console::WriteLine("Could not send data to arduino");
                }
            }
            serialPort->Close();
            return true;
        }

        void ArduinoInterface::readArduinoSerial() {
            StringComparer^ stringComparer = StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            while (has_serial)
            {
                try
                {
                    String^ message = serialPort->ReadLine();
                    if (stringComparer->Equals("a5", message)) {  // comparing does not work as expected and int's something ToDo
                        Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor::Green;
                        Console::WriteLine("#### Will try to send something to Arduino");
                        this->sendArduinoCommand("\n");
                        this->sendArduinoCommand("ON");
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException^) {}
            }
        }
    }
```